# meaning of int (*[n] tab)[m]

Tags: c++, c, pointers, multidimensional-array, declaration

I know we can define pointer to array  like this :
`int (*ptr)[size]` for 1-d and 2-d array and
`int (*ptr)[size1][size2]` for 3-d array.

But I don't understand the meaning of :

`int (*[n] ptr)[size]`. Is it the same like `int (* ptr)[n][size]` ?

Can someone explain me, please ?

Comment: Please don't tag multiple languages, except if you are asking about differences between the two. Tag only the language that you are actually using.

Comment: Also, as far as I can tell, this is not valid syntax in either of the two languages (macros aside). Please show where you saw this or which example actually compiled.

Comment: Where did you see `int (*[n] ptr)[size];`? Can you put that in context?

Comment: Ok @user17732522. Sorry for multiple languages taging.

Answer (score 1):

This declaration

```
int (*[n] ptr)[size];
```

is incorrect. It seems you mean

```
int (* ptr[n])[size];
```

This declares an array of `n` pointers to arrays of the type `int[size]`.

As for these declarations

```
int (*ptr)[size]; 
int (*ptr)[size1][size2];
```

then the first declares a pointer to one-dimensional array and the second one declares a pointer to two-dimensional array.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { n = 3, size = 3 };

    int a1[size] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int a2[size] = { 4, 5, 6 };
    int a3[size] = { 7, 8, 9 };

    int( *ptr[n] )[size] =
    {
        &a1, &a2, &a3
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (const int *p = *ptr[i]; p != *ptr[i] + size; p++)
        {
            printf( "%d ", *p );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Comment: Thank you @Vlad.
Your answer is correct.

Comment: @Enock If so then select the answer as the best answer and your reputation will be increased.:)